# Matching 2 regex's upon a certain criteria?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a large text file in the format of.

```
english word: spanish equivalent words here;
english word: spanish equivalent words here;
for about 1000 lines
```

What I need to do is find the words that the english word is the same as the spanish word except that the last letter 'e' has been changed to an 'o'
So, all english words that end in 'e', their spanish equivalent word is the exact same spelling except the last letter is an 'o' not an 'e'.
I hope that made sense:

For example I'll make up a word

```
thiswordE: spanishwordO; would be returned whilst
thisword: spanishwordO;  would not
thisword: spanishword; would also not be returned
```

I have tried to isolate this with:

```
awk '/[^e:]*e:/ && /[^o;]*o;/ {print}' a.txt
```

and

```
awk '/.*(e:|o;)/ {print}' a.txt
```

Neither has worked for me.. can someone help me out? 
Or point me in the right direction?

Also say I used awk to find a specific expression, how would I set a variable equal to this regex?

For example if I had the regex for the above file

```
awk '/...:/'   (so the last 3 letters before the :)
```

and wanted to set a variable equal to the result of that regex, how would I do that?

If you give me a straight up answer, can you explain how it works please?

Comment: With homework questions, make sure to stipulate limitations on tools  or techniques (awk _or_ sed, or _any_ UNIX filter?) that must or may be used and how the output is expected (in this case, do you need a text file with the results? or do you need to have a program that can merely print them to the screen? in-place modification of the file, or making a copy and putting it elsewhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work (unless there's something I don't know that's special about awk):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)[eE]:\s*\1[oO];.*
```

It allows all cases (without a switch), so just remove the capital letters where you don't need them or where you don't want to allow them. The last `.*` allows anything after the semicolon and before a newline. The `\1` is a backreference to what was matched by the *first* expression contained in parentheses, and the `\s` is any whitespace (including newlines)

Just ask if you'd like more explanation.

Edit: this is a general regex, and is not compatible with awk, as awk does not support backreferences - see the [follow-up question by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929516/my-sed-is-close-but-not-quite-there-can-you-help-please) for clarification on its use in sed, rather than awk.

Comment: The /1 back reference is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, new there had to be something like that

Comment: Hi there "Code Jockey", not sure if you're going to get this... but I can't seem to make your code work. I'm getting an "Invalid back reference" error, I'm trying to implement your code within sed as awk doesn't support backreferencing very well.

Comment: @Max Okie doke - I'm not an awk/sed guru by any means (I seem to remember using them at least once in the past...?), and I _think_ you'd need backreferences to do this, but you could help by at least adding a [tag:sed] tag to your question (you've got room for one more) and possibly rewriting or adding to your question with some of the `sed` things you've tried. I'm always up for learning, so I'm gonna spend some time looking for the answer, but if I were you, I'd keep trying to figure it out, and updating your question with your findings  to show research effort. Someone else may also help.

Comment: Which awk is this? The standard doesn't document any such backreference support, and I can't find it in the GNU Awk User's Guide (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp). Undocumented feature?