# my sed is close... but not quite there, can you help please?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to print only the lines that meet the criteria : "worde:" and "wordo;"
I got this far:

```
sed -n '/\([a-z]*\)\1e:\1o;/p;'
```

But it doesn't quite work. 
Can someone please perfect it and tell me exactly how its a fixed version/what was wrong with mine?
(Please note there are no capital letters ever, hence why I didn't bother including that within my initial character range)

Thanks heaps,

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  How are its results different from what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

This will handle lines where "worde:wordo;" (nothing between the words) appears:

```
sed -n '/\([a-z]*\)e:\1o;/p;'
```

If you need to allow for characters BETWEEN the words, you'll need something like this:

```
sed -n '/\([a-z]*\)e:.*\1o;/p;'
```

Comment: To point out the perhaps not-so-obvious, drop the `\1` before the `e`

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to match lines which contain both `worde:` and `wordo;`

```
 sed -n '/worde:/{/wordo;/p}' infile
```

The `-n` parameter prevents sed from printing the pattern space (`infile`), the first regex matches, then control flows into the block, if the regex isn't matched, then the line is ignored. Inside the block, the if the second regex is matched, the line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

One way using alternation:

```
sed -n '/word\(e:\|o;\)/ p' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement to use capture groups? I went without them.

`$ sed -n '/[\w]*[oe][:;]/p'`

- `[\w]*` - Match any word character. (if you really want only `[a-z]`, swap
  that back in)
- `[oe]` - Those word characters must end in an `e` or
  `o`
- `[:;]` - And then have a `:` or `;`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^\(.*\)[eE]:\s*\1[oO];/!d' file
```